# How to override equals without increasing cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I was recently overriding some `equals` methods in domain objects of my recent Java project. As we are using Sonar to calculate our code metrics, I immediately saw the cyclomatic complexity of these classes increasing above a threshold.

I'm wondering if there is a clever way, pattern or option at all to keep this metric low although having a little more complex `equals` method.

EDIT: Here is one of my examples that I have, nothing really specific I would say, just so that we know what we are talking about.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof MyKey) {
  MyKey other = (MyKey) o;
  if (this.foo.longValue() == other.getFoo().longValue() &&
    this.bar.equalsIgnoreCase(other.getBar()) &&
    this.foobar.shortValue() == other.getFoobar().longValue()){
    return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  int hash = 3;
  hash = 53 * hash + foo.hashCode();
  hash = 53 * hash + bar.hashCode();
  hash = 53 * hash + foobar.hashCode();
  return hash;
}
```

Comment: You can't add code without adding code, I'm afraid. If the logic of the over-ridden method is reusable, you can reduce the total increase by reusing it through inheritance, but there will still be an increase.

Comment: Maybe you should be less of a slave to Sonar. If you write bad code that pleases Sonar's robotic mind, it'll still be bad code.

Comment: I think you might wanna try `Objects.equals` method. That way you'll eliminate extra if statements.

Comment: @Enigo `Objects.equals(a, b)` just calls `a.equals(b)` but adds null checks, so that won't reduce anything.

Comment: @Kayaman it would reduce for sonar since sonar would analyse only end-code and not the sources or JDK

Comment: @Enigo No it wouldn't because he still needs to implement the `equals()` method.

Comment: Using `Objects.equals()` does help, as it reduces checks on nulls (which add to cyclomatic complexity)

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. Objects.equlas method should be used in overiden equals method.

Comment: You can also test putting the @Generated annotation on your equals() method and see if that causes Sonar to ignore it in its complexity calculation -- I couldn't confirm that it does.

Comment: @Avinash there is nothing specific about what I have there, just a bunch of if statements + instance of, so I would say that is a pretty regular usage

Comment: @Kayaman you are definitely right with the sonar slave :D and in general I don't care too much about the stats if they have some obvious reason to be like that. Nevertheless, going through the details I started reasoning about the topic and just out of interest I posted this question to start up some discussion if there is really some clever way to deal with that. All inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Apache's EqualsBuilder:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) { return false; }
  if (obj == this) { return true; }
  if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
    return false;
  }
  MyClass rhs = (MyClass) obj;
  return new EqualsBuilder()
             .appendSuper(super.equals(obj))
             .append(field1, rhs.field1)
             .append(field2, rhs.field2)
             .append(field3, rhs.field3)
             .isEquals();
}
```

Comment: Fair enough option to increase he complexity a bit

Comment: Normally, constructing new objects is discouraged inside `equals` and `hashcode`. The reason for this is that during lookup operations (e.g. in a list.indexOf(...)) this method is invoked *multiple* times, generating a pile of very short-lived objects. It results in a performance penalty, which is delayed to the moment the garbage collector kicks in.

Comment: That's not the case with modern JIT compilers.  Escape analysis should pick up that EqualsBuilder does not escape the scope of the `equals` function and therefore does not need to be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't but you should always check for `null`s. `foo` could be `null`, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

```
this.foo.longValue() == other.foo.longValue()
```

Luckily [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) utility class saves you from a lot of problems as it automatically checks for `null`s.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null)
        return false;

    if (!(object instanceof MyObject))
        return false;

    MyObject other = (MyObject) object;

    //@formatter:off
    return Objects.equals(getX(), other.getX()) &&
           Objects.equals(getY(), other.getY()) &&
           Objects.equals(getZ(), other.getZ()));
    //@formatter:on
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getX(), getY(), getZ());
}
```

If the fields to check are a lot you can optionally add this at the beginning of the `equals` method.

```
if (object == this)
    return true;
```

In theory it can save some computation in some edge case.

The only thing that really helps, in my opinion, is good indentation. I always wrap those line between a pair of `//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on`. It's boilerplate code, anyway: very easy to write, very easy to make mistakes.

In your case, though, you're checking equality using `equalsIgnoreCase`. It's a pity `Objects` doesn't have such a method. You can build your own pretty easily.

```
public final class Strings {
    public static boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String a, String b) {
        return a == null ? b == null : a.equalsIgnoreCase(b);
    }

    private Strings() {
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
return Objects.equals           (getX(), other.getX()) &&
       Strings.equalsIgnoreCase (getY(), other.getY()) &&
       Objects.equals           (getZ(), other.getZ()));
```

Comment: You don't need a null check before calling `object instanceof MyObject`. If object is null, the instanceof operator will return false.